# Parameterised view wrapper for PostgreSQL functions

Tags: postgresql, function, view, wrapper

We have tried to create view wrapper for PostgreSQL functions.
For that, we achieved to create a view with the function call in the view definition with static values in the function call.

eg:

> CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.my_view  AS  SELECT
> insertfunction('test', 1) AS insertfunction;

But unable to create a parameterised-view for passing our values to function call.

Any solution?

Thanks in advance
Chinnu M V

Comment: What is the issue you are trying to resolve with the wrapper functions. There may be other solutions for that issue, but without knowing what it is, the community cannot make any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot to pass parameters from view to inner function. This functionality is impossible in Postgres, and what I know in any database.